# _thread a function inside class returned "TypeError: func_one() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-multithreading, nameerror

```
import _thread
class cl:

    def func_one(self, conn):
        ...

    def func_two(self):
        str_key = "ABC"
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.func_one, (self,str_key))
```

Once interpreted, it returned the following:

```
TypeError: func_one() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have tried threading func_one() without self. in the beginning (self.func_one()) but then it returns

```
NameError: name 'func_one' is not defined
```

What should I do if I want to thread func_one() from func_two() ? They are in the same class cl().

I call func_two() using the following:

```
if(__name__ == "__main__"):

  c = cl()
  c.func_two()
```

UPDATE:

I found a solution to the issue:

```
import _thread
class cl:

    def func_one(self, conn, tmp):
        ...

    def func_two(self):
        str_key = "ABC"
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.func_one, (str_key,None))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `_thread.start_new_thread(self.func_one, (self,str_key))` you are calling self two times, one when adding the function pointer and the second one as an argument.

`func_one` is receiving `self, self, str_key` as arguments when it was expecting `self, str_keys`

It should work after removing the self inside the parenthesis as following:

`_thread.start_new_thread(self.func_one, (str_key))`

Comment: _thread.start_new_thread( self.func_one, (str_key) ) return 'TypeError: 2nd arg must be a tuple'

Comment: Add a comma after `str_key` so it is `(str_key,)`